# PHP : Sum different values of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, sum

I need to sum totals for 'in' and 'ou', [a] through [t]
The array.

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [in] => Array
            (
                [a] => 3
                [b] => 0
                [c] => 0
                [d] => 0
                [e] => 0
                [f] => 0
                [o] => 0
                [t] => 3
            )

        [ou] => Array
            (
                [a] => 0
                [b] => 0
                [c] => 1
                [d] => 0
                [e] => 0
                [f] => 0
                [o] => 0
                [t] => 1
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [in] => Array
            (
                [a] => 0
                [b] => 0
                [c] => 0
                [d] => 0
                [e] => 0
                [f] => 0
                [o] => 0
                [t] => 0
            )

        [ou] => Array
            (
                [a] => 0
                [b] => 0
                [c] => 0
                [d] => 1
                [e] => 2
                [f] => 0
                [o] => 0
                [t] => 3
            )
    )
)
```

The following is how I am calculating totals 'in'+'ou'.
However, I seem to be stuck in a rut when it comes to the individual totals of 'in' a,b,c,d,e,f,t and 'ou' a,b,c,d,e,f,t.

```
//get day total
foreach($arr as $array){
    foreach($array as $inou){
        foreach(array_keys($inou) as $value){
            if(isset($total[$value])){
                $total[$value] += $inou[$value];
            }else{
                $total[$value] = $inou[$value];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output should look something like

```
in(
[a] => 3
[b] => 0
[c] => 0
...
[t] => 3
)
ou(
[a] => 0
[b] => 0
[c] => 1
[d] => 1
[e] => 2
[f] => 0
[t] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```
        $sumIN = 0; 
        $sumOU = 0;
        foreach($arr as $innerArr)
        {
            $sumIN += array_sum($innerArr['in']);
            $sumOU += array_sum($innerArr['ou']);
        }
```

Comment: I need each total IN(a => total, b => total,...) and ou(a => total, b => total,...)